# Xamarin - .aar Java Binding - The name '[method name]' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, java-binding

I am trying to create binding for [Facebook Notification](https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications) .aar library.

However I am getting compile errors:

[image]

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0103  The name 'CreateAsset' does not exist in the current
>   context   FBNotifications C:\Users\jakub\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\FBNotifications\FBNotifications\obj\Release\generated\src\Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.Handlers.BitmapAssetHandler.cs  344 Active
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0103  The name 'CreateView' does not exist in the current
>   context   FBNotifications C:\Users\jakub\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\FBNotifications\FBNotifications\obj\Release\generated\src\Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.Handlers.BitmapAssetHandler.cs  350 Active

The methods that have the problem are following:

[image]

```
// This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetHandler
        global::Java.Lang.Object global::Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetHandler.CreateAsset (global::Org.Json.JSONObject p0, global::Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetCache p1)
        {
            return global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<Java.Lang.Object>(CreateAsset (p0, p1));
        }

        // This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetHandler
        global::Android.Views.View global::Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetHandler.CreateView (global::Java.Lang.Object p0, global::Android.Content.Context p1)
        {
            return CreateView (global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<global::Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.Handlers.BitmapAssetHandler.BitmapAsset>(p0), p1);
        }
```

I can see that the code issue can be fixed like this:

```
// This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetHandler
        global::Java.Lang.Object global::Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetHandler.CreateAsset (global::Org.Json.JSONObject p0, global::Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetCache p1)
        {
            return global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<Java.Lang.Object>(((AssetManager.IAssetHandler)this).CreateAsset (p0, p1));
        }

    // This method is explicitly implemented as a member of an instantiated Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetHandler
    global::Android.Views.View global::Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.AssetManager.IAssetHandler.CreateView (global::Java.Lang.Object p0, global::Android.Content.Context p1)
    {
        return ((AssetManager.IAssetHandler)this).CreateView (global::Java.Interop.JavaObjectExtensions.JavaCast<global::Com.Facebook.Notifications.Internal.Asset.Handlers.BitmapAssetHandler.BitmapAsset>(p0), p1);
    }
```

I thought that creating a partial class for BitmapAssetHandler and putting there the corrected method while removing it in **Metadata.xml** would fix it but it doesn't seem like it.

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.notifications.internal.asset.handlers']/class[@name='BitmapAssetHandler']/method[@name='CreateAsset']" />
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.notifications.internal.asset.handlers']/class[@name='BitmapAssetHandler']/method[@name='CreateView']" />
```

If I do that then I get error that the methods exist twice (somehow they do not get removed from the generated code). I hope it's not too complex of a problem. Is my approach correct? Or is there something else needed to be done to be able to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**remove-node** element does the trick.

```
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook.notifications.internal.asset.handlers']/class[@name='BitmapAssetHandler']" />
```

Comment: Hey man, have you had much experience with the bindings at all? I have a few specific issues that I desperately need to consult someone with and I am battling to find anyone who can help me?

Comment: @Killua hey, just an average experience. Feel free to post your question on SO it should get sorted.